# Starting an application that is in resources C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to run an executable that is in my resources.

Here is my current code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Properties.Resources.Application);
```

I know why it is not currently working. Although I do not know how to make it actually work

I am sorry if this description isn't very descriptive.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "I know why it is not currently working." you should actually explain why you think it is not working. You may have an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tip. What I meant is that I know I can't simply start a process just with the bytes of an application. Sorry If I was unclear

Comment: Don't put `[Answered]` in your title. You mark a question answered by checking the box on an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application in the resources is just a `byte[]`, you can't call `Process.Start(` on a `byte[]` it expects a path. Save the file to disk in a temporary folder and then execute the temporary file.

```
string path = GetTempFilePath();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, Properties.Resources.Application);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that !

Comment: While it is nice answer make sure to edit question with demonstration of effort that OP should have put in and remove "thank you notes".

Comment: Note that many antivirus utilities prevent programs from starting executables in the temporary folders.

Comment: Yes, this is a common issue, choosing the `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)` folder will usually work ok. Just make sure you make a sub folder, I think the default rights lets a user create a folder but not create files in the root directory, if you make a folder you should have rights to write to it.